# Cannot create new Object within Schema Builder, while doing Trailhead Tutorial

Tags: lightning-experience, custom-object, trailhead, schema-builder

## The Error Message:

> The value of the "le" parameter contains a character that is not allowed or the value exceeds the maximum allowed length. Remove the character from the parameter value or reduce the value length and resubmit. If the error still persists, report it to our Customer Support team. Provide the URL of the page you were requesting as well as any other related information.

Sometimes it's also *The value of the "to" parameter [...]*.
Why is this error happening and how can I proceed in my trailhead lesson?
I have tried several times with different naming conventions, same error.

I did find [this Forum Thread on Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005OIKQA2), but it didn't provide any help. The only thing that seemed to work was, to create the object inside the *Setup > Object Manager*. Before I do that I figured to ask for help.

### Error Image:

[image]

### My new Object:

[image]

Comment: Check to see if you have a trailing space in the object name.

Comment: Actually, it sounds like a relationship definition issue given the mention of "to"... ignore me.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check the reason but you should check some these check boxes
[image]
It worked for me